# binomial distributions and their transforming (6.37-6.39)

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-coefficients, game-theory

I'm lost and frustrated. I don't know how the author (Karl Sigmund; The Calculus of Selfishness) transforms 6.37 in the book pages imaged below:

$$ P_y = \sigma w^{N-1} + rc\frac{x}{1-w}\sum_{h=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{h}
(1-w)^h w^{N-h-1} \left(\frac{h}{h+1}\right) \;\; (6.37) $$

to 6.39 in the picture:

$$ P_y = \sigma w^{N-1} + rc\frac{x}{1-w}\left( 1 - \frac{1-w^N}{N(1-w)}\right)
\;\; (6.39) $$

Can anybody help me? I am a lawyer by training, so I am learning the mathematics required for evolutionary game theory bit by bit.  So far I have always managed to put things together eventually; this however seems to elude me. My own thoughts so far are probably not helpful, but I'll try:

I am assuming I am supposed to use the expected value of binomial distributions. However, if I use 6.38:

$$ \binom{N-1}{h} = \binom{N}{h+1} \frac{h+1}{N} \;\; (6.38) $$

my binomial coefficient would not fit the sum. My next guess would be that I should try to fit the sum to the binomial coefficient: As h=0 can be ignored, maybe one could add to the sum so it goes from $h=1$ to $N$, and then subtract it in another term), but puzzling around with it has not given me any answer that looks like 6.39. My guess is that somehow the fact that the sum from $i$ to $(N-1)$ of $w^i$ is $(1-w^N)/(1-w)$ has a role to play, but so far I am just stuck.

[image: Binomial Distribution in Game Theory]

Comment: Welcome to this site! Images containing your questions are not likely to get you an answer here, for several reasons: an image is not keyword-searchable; it may render badly on some computers; and most importantly, they do not allow the other users to appreciate your own efforts in trying to answer your question, and thus see exaclty where your problem is.  I would recommend typing your question and making it precise, showing what you know and what you don't about your problem.  Otherwise, it is quite likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon thank your for your comment, i am new to this site, i uploaded a picture because i didnt know how to type out the formulas. And as I am not a mathematician by training, i didnt include my own ideas thinking they'd be rather ridicolous. I have edited the post to include them however, maybe that will get me closer to an answer

Comment: @hardmath thank you very much, i edited the post to include the author and name of the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In going from 6.37 to 6.39 we need to prove that:

$$\sum_{h=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{h} (1-w)^h w^{N-h-1} \left(\frac{h}{h+1}\right) = 1 - \frac{1-w^N}{N(1-w)} \qquad\qquad\text{(*)}$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \\
\text{LHS} &=& \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} h\binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^h w^{N-h-1} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(using 6.38)} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{N(1-w)} \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} h\binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^{h+1} w^{N-h-1} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{N(1-w)} \left[ \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} (h+1)\binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^{h+1} w^{N-h-1} - \sum_{h=0}^{N-1} \binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^{h+1} w^{N-h-1} \right] \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{N(1-w)} \left[ N(1-w) - \left[ ((1-w)+w)^N-w^N \right] \right] \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(see (a), (b) below)} \\
&=& 1- \dfrac{1-w^N}{N(1-w)} \\
&=& RHS.
\end{eqnarray*}

Notes:

(a) $\sum\limits_{h=0}^{N-1} (h+1)\binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^{h+1} w^{N-h-1}$ is the expansion of the expectation of a binomial random variable with parameters $N$  and $1-w$. Hence it has value $N(1-w)$. That is, if $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ then $np=E(X)=\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}x\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n-1}(x+1)\binom{n}{x+1}p^{x+1}(1-p)^{n-x-1}$.

(b) $\sum\limits_{h=0}^{N-1} \binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^{h+1} w^{N-h-1}$ is the binomial expansion of $((1-w)+w)^N$ but the sum is missing the term for $h=-1$ which has value $w^N$. So $\sum\limits_{h=0}^{N-1} \binom{N}{h+1} (1-w)^{h+1} w^{N-h-1} = ((1-w)+w)^N-w^N$.